# How to get selected value in data-tagger attribute in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown list field called "Bug category" which includes four options:
software, hardware, tools, documentation.
My HTML:

```
<div class="form-field string  required  request_custom_fields_25376063" >
      <label for="request_custom_fields_25376063">Bug Category</label>
      <input type="hidden" name="request[custom_fields][25376063]" id="request_custom_fields_25376063" autocomplete="off" data-tagger="[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;-&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Software&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;software&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Hardware&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;hardware&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Tools&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;bug_tools&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Documentation&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;bug_documentation&quot;}]" />


        <p>Which type of bugs do you want to report?</p>

    </div>
```

The data-tagger attribute includes the selection values:

```
data-tagger="[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;-&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Software&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;software&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Hardware&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;hardware&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Tools&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;bug_tools&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Documentation&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;bug_documentation&quot;}]"
```

I want to change the form based on different selection of the bug category field. How can I get the value of selected option in the data-tagger attribute?

My Javascript code:

```
alert("value is:"+ $(this).attr('data-tagger').val()); // doesn't work
alert("value is:"+ $(this).attr('data-tagger')); //shows "Undefined" when I select option
```

**Edited:**

```
 var bug_category = $('input#request_custom_fields_25376063').parent();

 bug_category.on('change',function(){
    alert("value is:"+  $(this).find(':selected').data('tagger')); // return null
    });
```

**More script code:**

25375983 - each kind of number represent a field in the form.

This code is generated from an app, which allows me show different fields based on different selection of "bug_category" field.

```
<script>var cfaRules = [
{"fieldType":"tagger","field":25376063,"value":"bug_documentation","select":[25375983,24342549,24399485,25376023,25454706,25454746,25454766,25454806,25454826,25375963],"formId":240243,"requireds":[25375963,25454706,25454766]},{"fieldType":"tagger","field":25376063,"value":"bug_tools","select":[25454746,25454766,25454806,25454826,25454706,25376023,25375983,25375963,24399485,24342549],"formId":240243,"requireds":[25375983,25454706,25454746,25454766]},{"fieldType":"tagger","field":25376063,"value":"hardware","select":[24342549,24399485,25375963,25375983,25376023,25454706,25454746,25454766,25454806,25454826],"formId":240243,"requireds":[24342549,24399485,25454706,25454766]},{"fieldType":"tagger","field":25376063,"value":"software","select":[25454706,24342549,24399485,25375963,25375983,25376023,25454746,25454806,25454766,25454826],"formId":240243,"requireds":[24399485,25376023,25454706,25454766,25454826]}]</script>
```

Comment: Show more code context. We don't know what `this` is because you don't show where you call those alerts. See [mcve]

Comment: Also, where is the `data-tagger` attribute in your html? I dont see it there

Comment: @DelightedD0D scroll to the right

Comment: @charlietfl indeed, I scrolled right past it

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, I edited my post.

Comment: You use `:selected` for `<option>` not `<input>`. Seems to be some html  or some plugin code missing because there is nothing shown that user could *"change"* since the `<input>` shown is `hidden`

Comment: IHi @charlietfl, yes, I added more code. I am wondering that why I can't get the value that I have selected, is it because it is hidden?

Comment: I don't know what is actually changing since user can't interact with a hidden field. Is there some plugin also doing something with that field?

Comment: no, the app that I mentioned is the only one. I guess the way Zendesk is using to select/store data is very rare... The software I am using is called Zendesk, which is a very popular ticket system software.

Comment: That really isn't relevant ... all the browser knows is html , css and script. There is something critical missing in what you are showing us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data) to get the value of `data` tags

```
alert($(this).data('tagger'));
```

---

**UPDATE**

If I understand the real problem correctly, what you want should be something like this

```js
// Get the categories on div's hidden input using .data()
var categories = $('div').find('input').data('tagger');

// Append each categories to the select tag
// e.g. <option value="value> label </option>
$.each(categories, function(key,value){
    $('#select_bug').append('<option value="' + value.value + '">' + value.label + '</option>');
});

// declare select tag to bug_category variable
var bug_category = $('#select_bug');

// Alert the value when selected option is changed
bug_category.on('change',function(){
    alert("value is : " +  $(this).find(':selected').val());
});
```

```html
<div class="form-field string  required  request_custom_fields_25376063" >
    <label for="request_custom_fields_25376063">Bug Category</label>
    <input 
        type="hidden" 
        name="request[custom_fields][25376063]" 
        id="request_custom_fields_25376063" 
        autocomplete="off" 
        data-tagger="[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;-&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Software&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;software&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Hardware&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;hardware&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Tools&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;bug_tools&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Documentation&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;bug_documentation&quot;}]" />

    <p>Which type of bugs do you want to report?</p>

    <!-- Add select tags to insert dropdown options -->
    <select id="select_bug">
    </select>
    <!-- or if you already have this select tag, use yours -->
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</div>
    
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If `$(this).attr('data-tagger')` doesn't work then neither will `$(this).data('tagger')`. Also provide a proper explanation with your answers

Comment: Oh. Point well taken. Sorry, I missed that. Might have something wrong with his selector.

Comment: @JenniferZou you need to provide more code context for anyone to really help

Comment: @JenniferZou Please check edited answer. If it still doesn't fit what you actually need. Kindly provide more of your codes for us to really understand how you want it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [jquery's .data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) method because it will also auto-magically parse the value to the correct type.

```js
var value = $('input').data('tagger');
console.log(typeof value);
console.log(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" 
   name="request[custom_fields][25376063]" 
   id="request_custom_fields_25376063" 
   autocomplete="off" 
   data-tagger="[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;-&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Software&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;software&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Hardware&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;hardware&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Tools&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;bug_tools&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Documentation&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;bug_documentation&quot;}]" />
```

Regarding your example code.

```
var bug_category = $('input#request_custom_fields_25376063').parent();
```

Makes literally no sense because the `.parent()` of your input field, the `div` cannot have a `change` event on it, so it cannot fire.

```
$(this).find(':selected').data('tagger')
```

If somehow this code was to fire, based on your example, find would return *Zero* elements because there are no elements that support `:selected`, thus `.data()` will always return undefined.

Comment: Still doesn't explain why attr() returns undefined

Comment: That's not the question.  The question is clearly *How to get selected value in data-tagger attribute in Javascript* which my answer clearly works.

Comment: Agree what you say about using data() but if attr() doesn't return anything neither will data(). The problem likely lies in what `this` is

Comment: Agree, it's also why I up-voted your first comment.  Once it's determined why `$(this)` isn't working, the correct solution is still to use `data()` regardless.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, I edited my post. Still return null with your code. I am not sure how to get the selected label value in the data-tagger.

Comment: @JenniferZou my example does not return null.  *Your code* doesn't make any sense.  Will update my answer as to why.